# I don't understand how this code works?

Tags: java

So I have an exam tomorrow in java, and there's this code of Queues that I don't get , this is the full class :

```
public class queues {

    static final int max = 5;
    static int[] queue = new int[max];
    static int t = 0, h = 0;

    static boolean isempty() {
        return t == h;
    }

    static boolean isfull() {
        return (t + 1) % max == h;
    }

    static void enqueue(int e) {
        if (isfull()) {
            System.out.println("Queue is Full");
        } else {
            queue[t] = e;
            t = (t + 1) % max;
        }
    }

    static int dequeue() {
        if (isempty()) {
            System.out.println("Queue is empty");
            return 0;
        } else {
            int temp = queue[h];
            queue[h] = 0;
            h = (h + 1) % max;
            return temp;
        }
    }
}
```

But what I don't get is the `enqueue()` method when **else** is executed .. Shouldn't the line `t=(t+1)%max;` be before `queue[t]=e;`, 
or shouldn't we write `queue[t=(t+1)%max]=e` instead? Because we are inserting an element in the address which is next to t, not t itself ..
Can someone explain to me how this insertion works ?

Comment: Follow naming conventions and format your code.

Comment: don't try to learn concept from code if you are beginner. First understand how queue works and the basic operations. Then try to code on your own.  Good luck!

Comment: simply go through the code for the case of an empty queue, you actually insert at `t`!

Comment: @uniquephase I know how queue works and this code is from my book. I understand it completely but this method :( thank you anyway.

Comment: The index of an array starts with `0`. If you switch the statements in the `else` the first insert would be at position 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the queue to be empty, so your t == 0. When you insert the first element with enqueue method, it should be placed at the 0 position of the int[] queue array. Then your pointer t increments, so that next time element would be inserted at the 1 position. Therefore, at first, the insertion is done, then your pointer is incremented, but not vice versa.

So, basically, your t is just a pointer which points to the cell a new element should be inserted in.